# how to share my GUI tkinter python with friends online without seeing the code

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, executable

I already finished my first GUI tkinter using python. I would like to share with my friends to give his feedback. Here is what I really want:

I would like to send him a link, when he clicks it, it should ask him for username and password (only one person). Then a pop window showing my program (GUI tkinter) with no codes or something else.

I know I can do an executable software, but I don't want him to download the file every single time for just feedbacks.

Please, help me find a solution or any better ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont there there is any other way other than exe, or u have to giv him ur code and he shud have python installed and be able to run it

Comment: What you need is a web application, not tkinter.

Comment: Thank you Cool Cloud & acw1668, I guess an exe file is the only one.